# SQL count(*) and distinct

Tags: sql

Why can't we use `count(distinct *)` in SQL? As in to count all distinct rows?

Comment: What do you mean by 'distinct rows'?

Comment: Do you have rows that are duplicated in the entire row, is that what you are trying to find?

Comment: Now when I think of it,because our tables are normalized we wont have exact same rows so its useless right?? Is this the reason??

Comment: @Myth17 If you have normalization at a level where primary keys, exist you are correct, all rows will be distinct in that case.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
select count(*) from (select distinct * from MyTable) as T
```

Although I strongly suggest that you re-think any queries that use `DISTINCT`. In a large percentage of cases, `GROUP BY` is more appropriate (and faster).

**EDIT:** Having read the question comments, I should point out that you should ***never*** ask the DBMS to do more work than actually needs doing to get a result. If you know in advance that there will not be any duplicated rows in a table, then don't use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @CHristian - hi, never seen it done that way before. out of curiosity ran it with an existing table on my end and i'm getting 'Incorrect syntax near ')' '. work in ms sql server? note - my select within the brackets runs perfectly

Comment: On Oracle DISTINCT and GROUP BY have the same execution plan because DISTINCT in implemented using GROUP BY.  So there should be no difference.

Comment: @Kamal: Sorry, forgot that SQL Server is a bit iffy with nested queries. Adding an alias name onto the end (`as T`) solved the problem.

Comment: @MrShiny: It's all about requesting the least amount of work to be done. Conceptually speaking, `GROUP BY` is asking for less work than `DISTINCT`, and will therefore *sometimes*, not always, result in a more efficient plan. See also the difference between `JOIN` and `EXISTS`.

Comment: I just used select Count(distinct COLUMN)  from MyTable as T and work fine.

Answer (score 11):

You can select all the columns in your table and group by...

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, count(*)
FROM someTable
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3
```

Comment: This doesn't actually get what the question asks though.

Answer (score 5):

why not?

```
select 
  count(distinct name)
from 
  people
```

Comment: Because two poeple could have the same name. The OP asked about COUNT(DISTINCT *).

Comment: Sorry, it was another text in the question when I answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed.

If you've got an identifier, though, you won't have any entirely distinct rows. But you could do for instance:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SenderID) FROM Messages
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a CTE in Sql Server 2005

```
;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT  DISTINCT Val1,Val2, Val3
        FROM    @Table
)
SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    cte
```

To answer the question, From the documentation

> Specifies that all rows should be
>   counted to return the total number of
>   rows in a table. COUNT(*) takes no
>   parameters and cannot be used with
>   DISTINCT. COUNT(*) does not require an
>   expression parameter because, by
>   definition, it does not use
>   information about any particular
>   column. COUNT(*) returns the number of
>   rows in a specified table without
>   getting rid of duplicates. It counts
>   each row separately. This includes
>   rows that contain null values.

Comment: When you say, "From the documentation" which documentation would that be?

Comment: Sql Server Help Documentation. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Answer (score 0):

some languajes may not be able to handle 'distinct *' so, if you want the distinction made through many columns you might want to use 'distinct ColumnA || ColumnB' , combining the values before judging if they are different. Be mindful whether your variables are numeric and your database handler can make automatic typecast to character strings.

Comment: This also isn't a full proof method as-is. For example, ('test', 'string') and ('tes', 't string') would look the same. You could do something with padding the strings, but it gets messy. Better IMO to just use a subquery with DISTINCT and then get a COUNT from that.

Answer (score -1):

COUNT(*) is the number of rows matching a query.

A row contains unique information such as rowid.  All rows are by definition distinct.

You must count the distinct instances of values in some field instead.

Comment: Why does a row contain unique information? It doesn't have to... it probably should but its not *required*.

Answer (score -2):

UberKludge, and may be postgre specific, but

```
select count( distinct table::text ) from table
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select count (Tag_no) from tab_raw_tag_value where tag_no in (select distinct tag_no from tab_raw_tag_value)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question